# How to create a 2 way aggregation/pivot in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this:

| Food | Rent | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Burger King | 2000 | SF |
| Applebee | 4000 | SF |
| Applebee | 6000 | NYC |
| Applebee | 3000 | LA |
| Safeway | 3500 | SD |
| Burger King | 2000 | SD |
| Burger King | 2000 | FL |

but I want to pivot/aggregate this so that all the rent from the west coast (SF+LA+SD) and east coast (NYC+FL) are added up by restaurant:

|  | West Coast Rent (SF+LA+SD) | East Coast Rent (NYC+FL) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Burger King | 4000 | 2000 |
| Applebee | 3000 | 6000 |
| Safeway | 3500 | 0 |

this is the code I used but I got stuck midd-way and didn't know what to do anymore:

```
select food,rent,restaurant, sum(case WHEN restaurant ='SF')
from table
group by food;
```

Comment: Have you searched S/O for `SQL PIVOT`? I'd include links, but I'll probably get one that just misses what you need, and there are numerous questions out there that might get you wher eyou need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  The correct syntax looks like this:

```
select food,
       sum(case WHEN location in ('SF', 'LA', 'SD') then rent else 0 end) as west_coast,
       sum(case WHEN location in ('NYC', 'FL') then rent else 0 end) as east_coast
from table
group by food;
```